# Can you trigger autoscaling in Google App Engine based on Cloud Pub/Sub queue?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I know you can configure autoscaling based on queue size when scaling a Compute Engine instance group, but I'm unsure of how I could replicate this behavior in a flexible App Engine based environment. Is this possible?

I want to be able to decouple my frontend service from my backend and allow them to work asynchronously, but I'm not sure how to scale the backend with  pub/sub queue size that can get very big. The only scaling options I see in `autoscaling` section of `app.yaml` have to do with CPU utilization.

Comment: Wouldn't a large pub/sub queue automatically drive the running backend instances CPU utilisation higher, thus (indirectly) serve as a GAE flex autoscaling trigger?

Comment: @DanCornilescu I was thinking that might be the case, but it's not necessarily guaranteed that CPU utilization will increase as a function of queue size. API calls or any other task that causes the main thread to idle could result in long latency but still low CPU utilization. Perhaps I need to implement multi-threading in the backend to process additional messages in order to get utilization up, but that seems unnecessary?

Comment: @DanCornilescu it would also beg the question of why autoscaling for pub/sub exists for GCE if that indirect scaling was satisfactory in all use cases?

Comment: GCE doesn't have the GAE autoscaling...

Comment: @DanCornilescu GCE can autoscale on stackdriver metrics for Cloud Pub/Sub

Comment: But that is different than the GAE auto-scaling (GCE doesn't run only GAE apps). Different tools for different jobs. And GAE apps can scale for reasons other then pub/sub.

Comment: I agree, I just want to know if it's possible to replicate that behavior of triggering autoscaling based on queue size metrics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App Engine Flexible environment currently only supports autoscaling based on a target cpu utilization (see [doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/reference/app-yaml#services) for scaling settings).

Also note that you can't set the actual number of running instances with autoscaling but only the "max_num_instances" value. You can update it to a higher value programmatically via the App Engine Admin API's [apps.services.versions.patch](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps.services.versions/patch) method, but the autoscaler will still decide to actually spawn new instances based on cpu utilization only.

The best option as you mentioned would be to allow concurrent requests and multi-threading in order to use each instance at its maximum potential. You could then tweak the cpu's target_utilization value to have new instances spawned if needed.